# Generate array of formatted strings from range in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, date, time

I'm dealing with Ruby on Rails application.

Just to be educated, I would like to know if it is possible to generate an array of formatted strings; in this particular situation - hours and minutes.

I want to get following array: ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"] from something like (9..12).to_a and something else ? What is the simpliest and cleanest way for this ?

Sorry if the question is stupid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this using [rjust](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rjust) for left padding.

```
(9..12).map{ |t| "#{t.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:00" }
#=> ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]
```

Comment: Wow! Nice, clean and clever! Super! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
(9..12).map{ |n| Time.new(0,1,1,n).strftime("%R") }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(9..12).map{ |t| "%02d:00" % t }
```